# Is it possible to establish an SSH tunnel between two Windows computers? (without a third-party web server)

Tags: postgresql, ssh, putty

The purpose of the question is to create a remote connection between two [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) databases. I currently use [Navicat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navicat). I've read a **lot** of tutorials about using [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) and [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) to create the SSH server, but it only works on the local test, when I try with the public IP address in the other computer it doesn't.

In order to prevent this to become a private / particular problem I'll stick with how to get an SSH tunnel without a web server between two Windows computers. This is really a general problem for Windows users. I've tried in six different computers at my company and two at home and all the time is the same answer. From the research I've done in forums and here on Stack Overflow this is a common problem. I've attached two pictures to show that an SSH server runs smooth locally, but when you use the IP address assigned by your [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider), it fails.

I'm starting to think that doing this in a Windows enviroment is a bad idea.. ps. 1- When you install bitvise it automatically 'opens' port 22, so I think it's not a port problem. 2- My company's Internet provider and home's are different so I think this isn't an ISP problem either. I don't know what more it can be...

http://matheus25.site90.net/itworks.jpg

http://matheus25.site90.net/itdoesntwork.jpg

Comment: Can you manually login via SSH from one machine to the other? Sounds like it could be a networking issue.

Comment: Start by describing what you are actually trying to achieve. You are mixing terms freely: `create the ssh server`? A it stands this is not a proper question.

Comment: I think I understand "create the ssh server" - unlike Linux or Unix, a Windows box won't have an SSH server installed out-of-the-box. However, what do you mean by "a remote connection between two postgresql databases" - what are you doing with this connection, exactly? Replication?

Comment: I'm sorry @ErwinBrandstetter and Balthus, i will try to make myself more clear this time. The end goal is to use an ssh connection to synchronize two databases (navicat has an inbuilt ssh login feature). Now, in order to achieve that I've installed a ssh server for windows (like openssh, bitvise, etc..). And the problem is, once the server is running, when i type 127.0.0.1 on the **destination** field in the session category it connects perfectly (localhost). But, when i type my public address, the one my isp assigned me, putty doesn't connect, it only opens cmd screen with the cursor stuck.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like one of the DB servers is actually also the server where you are running the client tools. The databases aren't connecting to each other *as such*, Navicat is pulling data/configuration from one and pushing it to the other. Does that sound right?

Comment: That's why I asked if it is possible at all to connect two computers running windows in two different locations; not in the same network.

Comment: @IMSoP That's what I want to achieve, but so far i cannot make a remote connection at all! All servers that appear are local..ps.thanks for your help, the comment above is a general comment it is not referring to your question

Comment: There's three tabs for doing remote connections: ssl, ssh and http. SSH seems to be the more simple, but still despite all my efforts i can't get it to work.. there's also a 'sync data' button where you can choose which databases you want to synchronize, which is currently working for local databases.

Comment: Please **edit** your question with all relevant information. Don't hide it in comments!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think a web server would be relevant in this case - SSH and HTTP are two completely unrelated protocols.

Comment: By web server i meant a cloud database like enterprisedb which is capable of doing ssh.. it is just to point that the goal is create a secure shell tunnel **directly** between the computers, without third parties..

Comment: If you want a tunnel, why not just establish a VPN connection? OpenVPN works fine as both the server and the client on Windows.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance @sayap, but if I did how would I configure the database connection? I've installed openvpn when i temporally gave up of ssh but despite the graphical interface I couldn't make it work..

Comment: After establishing a VPN connection, both of the machines will have an additional IP in the same subnet. Basically you can treat them as two machines in the same LAN, with slightly unstable connection (if your dynamic public IP changes, OpenVPN will automatically reconnect after a few minutes of downtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but exactly what you need to do will depend on exactly what setup you have. A web server should not be necessary or relevant. I'm not clear exactly what connection you want, but in general you need 3 things:

1. An SSH *client*, on every machine that needs to login to a remote database
2. An SSH *server*, on every machine that needs to accept remote logins
3. The ability to connect from one to the other through whatever firewalls etc sit in between

Item 1 is trivial: you can install PuTTY, use its graphical application for testing, and the command-line `plink` for automated connections. It's possible that Navicat can also act as the SSH client itself, logging in over SSH and configuring the tunnel automatically, but I have no experience of that tool. PuTTY will certainly be useful for initial testing though.

Item 2 might be a little trickier: you'll need to install the SSH server and configure appropriate logins.

Item 3 may or may not be an issue: there may be a firewall next to both client and server which could restrict the traffic (generally on port 22) that constitutes the SSH connection, or it may already be open and ready to use. One way to test this is by running `telnet address.of.remote.machine 22` from another location. If the connection fails, then something is blocking connections on that port; in that case, you will probably need to talk to the host of the server to ask them if you can have that port opened up.

Once you have that all working so that you can login manually with PuTTY, you need to configure your SSH tunnels, *on the client end*. These basically work by making a local network port on the client (say, port 5433) connect, via the SSH connection, to a different port on the server (for a standard Postgres install, port 5432).

So when you tell Navicat to connect to "localhost:5433", the connection is "tunnelled" and actually gives you data from port 5432 on some other server somewhere else. You will *not* tell Navicat that it is connecting to the public address of the remote machine, since that will just go over the public Internet, not the SSH tunnel.

Comment: Thanks for your support @IMSoP, you've covered the steps better than any other tutorial so far. But the big challenge appears when you move from local network to internet. I suggest you take a look on the update part of my question to understand what happens to a normal user when it uses his public ip.

Comment: I would very much think this is a firewall issue somewhere, most likely at your ISP: if they don't natively support SSH, they are likely to have closed that port in their firewall. One way to test this is by running `telnet address.of.remote.machine 22` from another location. If the connection fails, then something is blocking connections on that port.

Comment: @MikaelBlomkvist Sorry, by "your ISP", I mean "the hosting provider of your remote server". You will probably need to ask them nicely if you can have port 22 opened, as it's probably not on their standard list for Windows servers.

Comment: Excellent idea! I've tried the telnet command and i presume it worked on port 23 because it prompted the login screen, but not on port 22.. any suggestions?

Comment: @Mikael The actual telnet protocol, on port 23 , is no use to you (and I'm surprised it's listening). A telnet connection to an SSH server wouldn't give you a login screen, it would be waiting for you to send it encrypted data. It's just useful as a stripped-down test of firewall rules.

Comment: It appeared 'Welcome to ATP Cli' and then to login.. but I'm gonna mark this question as answered as your instructions for normal usage are more than enough, and if I manage to solve the problem i come back here. Thanks for all @IMSoP

Comment: Now I saw the 'Closed Question' warning.. what's going on with SO? To make a simple remote connection between two windows computers is a serious issue when you don't have a static public IP. Lot's of users find this difficulty, i have personal experience to say this otherwise it wouldn't exist paid programs as teamviewer, dropbox, ammy etc for windows. Congrats you've just prevented community of getting an answer.

Comment: @MikaelBlomkvist If you look at the reason given for closing, it's not that the question is not useful, it's that it was deemed off-topic on a site about software development, as it's more of a system administration / software usage issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to re-invent [**database replication**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/different-replication-solutions.html) consider one of the production-ready solutions.

---

If you just want to copy selected data between databases, you can use the additional module [**dblink**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/dblink.html) to copy data *directly* from DB to DB, optionally **encrypted with SSL**. The servers can be *anywhere* in the net.

A basic example to fetch data from another db (anywhere in the net) could look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id integer, col1 text, col2 text);

SELECT dblink_connect('myserver');
-- FDW postgresql, USER MAPPING FOR postgres; PW from .pgpass

INSERT INTO tbl (tbl_id, col1, col2)  -- same table exists on foreign server
SELECT *
FROM   dblink('SELECT tbl_id, col1, col2 FROM tbl') AS b(
        tbl_id integer
       ,col1 text
       ,col2 text);

SELECT dblink_disconnect();
```

You could easily encapsulate this in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS text AS
$func$
 -- code from above goes here
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT foo();
```

I am using a [`FOREIGN SERVER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createserver.html) here. Basic example statements to create:

[FDW](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createforeigndatawrapper.html) (only if you don't already have it):

```
CREATE FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgresql VALIDATOR postgresql_fdw_validator;
```

[Foreign server](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createserver.html):

```
CREATE SERVER myserver
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgresql
OPTIONS (hostaddr '1.2.3.4', port '5432', dbname 'mydb', sslmode 'require');
```

By adding `sslmode 'require'` to your connection string you enforce SSL encrypted connections only. [Read more in the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-connect.html)

[User mapping](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createusermapping.html):

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
SERVER myserver OPTIONS (user 'postgres');
```

And to simplify things and make it safe I am using the [**`.pgpass`** file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-pgpass.html) to provide a password. You probably need to *read* some documentation before you use any of this.

Comment: Erwin i'm very grateful for your time elaborating the answer and seems to be a much more professional approach. I've read a lot about replication before start doing synchronization through navicat; i've chosen the latter because there's only 2 tables involved and replication augmented the conflicts issues. So, i'm already satisfied pressing the data synchronization button and it inserts / updates the tables, the big thing it only works locally,therefore i'm struggling for weeks now on how to make this process on a **remote** level. SSH seems to be the answer, but i can't get it to work.

Comment: In order to prevent this to become a private / particular problem i'll stick with how to get a ssh tunnel without a web server. This is really a general problem for windows users. I've tried in 6 different computers at my company and 2 at home and all the time is the same answer. From the research i've done in forums and here in SO this is a common problem. I've attached two pictures to show that a ssh server runs smooth locally, but when you use the ip assigned by your isp, it fails. I'm starting to think that doing this on a windows enviroment is a bad idea..

Comment: http://matheus25.site90.net/itworks.jpg http://matheus25.site90.net/itdoesntwork.jpg

Comment: @Erwin The "anywhere in the net" part has the same requirements as any DB connection, including pg_hba.conf at the Postgres level, and various firewall considerations at the network level.